# refer to quoted column name in a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, r-glue

I want to use the `na_omit` function from the *collapse* package in a user-defined function. `na_omit` requires a column name to be in quotes as one of its arguments. If I didn't need the column name in quotes, I could just refer to the column name in double braces, `{{col}}`, [as mentioned in this vignette, "Programming with dplyr"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). If I refer to the column using the *glue* package, such as `glue::glue("{col}")`, I receive errors.

Here is a reprex:

```
my_df <-
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      c(
        "V9G","Blue",
        NA,"Red",
        "J4C","White",
        NA,"Brown",
        "F7B","Orange",
        "G3V","Green"
      ),
      nrow = 6,
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(NULL,
                      c("color_code", "color"))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

my_func <- function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    collapse::na_omit(cols = c(glue("{col}"))) #Here is the code that fails
}

my_func(my_df, color_code)
```

The expected output can be generated with the following:

```
my_df %>% 
  collapse::na_omit(cols = c("color_code"))
```

and should produce:

```
#  color_code  color
#1        V9G   Blue
#2        J4C  White
#3        F7B Orange
#4        G3V  Green
```

How should I refer to a quoted column name that's a parameter and an argument of a function within a user-defined function in R?

Comment: have you read https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html?

Comment: try `function(df, col) { col <- as.character(substitute(col)); ...; }`

Comment: I don't have `collapse` installed so I cannot test

Comment: What error do you get? When I try to copy your code, I just get an `Error: object 'color_code' not found ` error, which goes away when I pass in `"color_code"` as a string and returns what I think is the expected output

Comment: Sebastian's solution is exactly what I was looking for. In particular, `as.character(substitute())`. I didn't see this in the dplyr vignette. I'll suggest an addition.

Comment: Suggesting a change to the *dplyr* vignette won't be appropriate in this case, as I now recognize. [See my comment to Sebastian's solution about what needs to be done for an unquoted column name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963235/refer-to-quoted-column-name-in-a-function-in-r#comment125471630_70964120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, collapse is mostly standard evaluation and its NSE features are based upon base R, so most of the rlang, glue stuff, `{{ }}`, etc. won't work, but you will have simpler and faster code. For base R NSE functional programming, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.

[As suggested by r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963235/refer-to-quoted-column-name-in-a-function-in-r/70964120#comment125449214_70963235), for a single column, a solution would be:

```
my_func <- function(df, col) { 
  col_char_ref <- as.character(substitute(col))
  df %>% 
    collapse::na_omit(cols = col_char_ref)
}
```

i.e. use `substitute()` to capture the expression and `as.character` or `all.vars` to extract the variables. For multiple columns a general solution is wrapping `fselect` e.g.

```r
library(collapse)
my_func <- function(df, ...) {
  cols <- fselect(df, ..., return = "indices")
  na_omit(df, cols = cols) 
}

my_func(wlddev, PCGDP:GINI, POP) |> head()
#>   country iso3c       date year decade                region
#> 1 Albania   ALB 1997-01-01 1996   1990 Europe & Central Asia
#> 2 Albania   ALB 2003-01-01 2002   2000 Europe & Central Asia
#> 3 Albania   ALB 2006-01-01 2005   2000 Europe & Central Asia
#> 4 Albania   ALB 2009-01-01 2008   2000 Europe & Central Asia
#> 5 Albania   ALB 2013-01-01 2012   2010 Europe & Central Asia
#> 6 Albania   ALB 2015-01-01 2014   2010 Europe & Central Asia
#>                income  OECD    PCGDP LIFEEX GINI       ODA     POP
#> 1 Upper middle income FALSE 1869.866 72.495 27.0 294089996 3168033
#> 2 Upper middle income FALSE 2572.721 74.579 31.7 453309998 3051010
#> 3 Upper middle income FALSE 3062.674 75.228 30.6 354950012 3011487
#> 4 Upper middle income FALSE 3775.581 75.912 30.0 338510010 2947314
#> 5 Upper middle income FALSE 4276.608 77.252 29.0 335769989 2900401
#> 6 Upper middle income FALSE 4413.297 77.813 34.6 260779999 2889104
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I could alternatively use `deparse(substitute())` to get the same desired output. Is this preferred?

Comment: I've clearly been living in a *dplyr* world for most of my R life. Even to achieve output like `my_df %>% collapse::ftransform(count = stringr::str_length(color))` in a user-defined function, I need to use something like the following, which seems quite verbose:`my_func <- function(df, col){env <- list2env(df, parent = parent.frame()); col <- substitute(col); df %>%  collapse::ftransform(count = stringr::str_length(eval(col, env)))
}; my_func(my_df, color)`

Comment: `deparse` is not as efficient as `as.character`

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide col name as a character, like:

```
my_func <- function(df, col){
  df %>% 
    collapse::na_omit(cols = c(glue("{col}"))) #Here is the code that fails
}

my_func(my_df, col = "color_code")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to first determine what environment in R you're programming in. Are you in *dplyr* or base R? If in *dplyr*, then reference the documentation for programming with [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), [rlang](https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html), [glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/), and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624840/15370142). If in base R, reference the [documentation on non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), especially wrapping quoted columns in `as.character(substitute())` and wrapping functions with unquoted columns in `eval(substitute())`.

It should be noted that both of the approaches above involve **non-standard evaluation**. Another approach is use **standard evaluation** (or some "combination" of standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation). [For example, see the issue raised in this link.](https://github.com/SebKrantz/collapse/issues/222)

Reasons for this question come, at least partially, from environment confusion. Here are some of the different approaches in a reprex.

**Data**

```
my_df <-
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      c(
        "V9G","Blue",
        NA,"Red",
        "J4C","White",
        NA,"Brown",
        "F7B","Orange",
        "G3V","Green"
      ),
      nrow = 6,
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(NULL,
                      c("color_code", "color"))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

**Packages**

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(glue)
```

***Functional Programming in base R (non-standard evaluation)***
**with a quoted column name:**

```
my_func <- function(df, col) {
  col_char_ref <- as.character(substitute(col)) #Use as.character(substitute()) to refer to a quoted column name
  df %>% 
    collapse::na_omit(cols = col_char_ref) 
}

my_func(my_df, color_code)

#Should generate output below
my_df %>% 
  collapse::na_omit(cols = "color_code")
```

**and with a non-quoted column name:**

```
my_func <- my_func <- function(df, col){
  df <- df # This makes sure "df" is available inside the function environment where we evaluate the ftransform expression
  eval(substitute(collapse::ftransform(df, count = stringr::str_length(col)))) # Wrap the function to be evaluated in eval(substitute())
}

 my_func(my_df, color)

 #Should generate output below
 my_df %>%  
  collapse::ftransform(count = stringr::str_length(color))
```

***Functional programming in dplyr (non-standard evaluation)***
**with a quoted column name using** *glue* **and** *dplyr* **functions:**

```
my_func <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  df %>%
    mutate(description := glue("color code: {pull(., {{col1}})}; color: {pull(., {{col2}})}"))
}

my_func(my_df, color_code, color)

#Should generate output below
my_df %>%
  mutate(description = glue("color code: {color_code}; color: {color}"))
```

**or with a quoted column name using a C language wrapper function:**

```
my_func <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  df %>%
    mutate(description := sprintf("color code: %s; color: %s", {{col1}}, {{col2}}))
}

my_func(my_df, color_code, color)

#Should generate output below
my_df %>%
  mutate(description = glue("color code: {color_code}; color: {color}"))
```

**and with a non-quoted column name:**

```
my_func <- function(df, col){
  df %>%  
    dplyr::mutate(count = stringr::str_length({{ col }}))
}

my_func(my_df, color)

#Should generate output below
my_df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(count = stringr::str_length(color))
```

***Correcting error-producing code***
The following code that produces an error provides a motivation for the two examples below:

```
my_func <- function(df, col){
  df <- df
  df %>%  
    collapse::na_omit(cols = as.character(substitute(col))) %>% 
    eval(substitute(collapse::ftransform(description = stringr::str_length(col))))
}

my_func(my_df, color_code)

#Error in ckmatch(cols, nam) : Unknown columns: col
```

The examples below are alternatives that do not produce errors.
***Functional Programming in base R (standard evaluation - requires column to be passed as character string in function)***

```
library(pkgcond)

my_func <- function(df, col) {
  if (!is.character(substitute(col)))
    pkgcond::pkg_error("col must be a quoted string") #if users aren't used to quoted strings as inputs to a function
  df <- na_omit(df, cols = col) 
  df$count <- stringr::str_length(.subset2(df, col))
  df
}

my_func(my_df, "color_code")

#Should generate output below
my_df %>% 
  na_omit(cols = "color_code") %>% 
  ftransform(description = stringr::str_length("color_code"))
```

***Functional Programming in base R ("combination" of standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation)***

```
my_func <- function(df, col){
  df <- df
  df <- collapse::na_omit(df, cols = as.character(substitute(col))) # Unlike the code with the error, the function is not piped (using %>%)
  eval(substitute(collapse::ftransform(df, description = stringr::str_length(col))))
}

 my_func(my_df, color_code)

 #Should generate output below
 my_df %>% 
  na_omit(cols = "color_code") %>% 
  ftransform(description = stringr::str_length("color_code"))
```

[More complex examples using the *collapse* package can be referenced at this link.](https://github.com/SebKrantz/collapse/issues/222#issuecomment-1032740048)